# advanced search query [rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, database-schema

I am trying to write a query for my application. I want to get all Articles whose title or the owner username is a given string (I send to my method params[:word]). The results should be ordered by:

1. First the articles of the current_user
2. The articles where the current_user has voted
3. Finally the articles of other users but only publics one

My db looks like:

[image]

Users has many articles, many votes.

One article belongs to a user, has many votes. And article owner cannot vote.

A vote should be associated to an Article and to a user.

My solution is get my own articles, later the articles which I voted, then the other public articles. All of this, using 3 different queries and append them to the same array, however, maybe I will get some repeated articles in the 3th query. Is there any other solution for that? maybe using only one query, having thousands records should be another problem.

Any help is very appreciated! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly avoid duplicate articles in your 3rd query by filtering out articles that match your current user or which have a vote from your current user.

Assuming you're doing `Article.where(article_type: 'public')` you can do

```
q = Article.where(article_type: 'public')

# Filter out articles owned by the current user
q = q.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)

# Filter out articles voted on by the current user
# This left joins the votes table to include the single row that will have
# recorded the vote for the current user on the article in question
# if the id of that left joined table is null then we know there 
# is no vote on the article for the current user and that it won't have
# been included in the second step
q = q.joins("left join votes on article_id = articles.id and user_id = #{User.sanitize(current_user.id)}"
q = q.where(votes: { id: nil })

articles = q # or q.limit(10) or somesuch
```

Or, as you say, more ideally you want to do a single query that encapsulates your ordering requirements. I'm not sure how efficient that is going to be so you might need to try it out. With a single query it is going to be much easier to paginate through articles. (You may also want to consider whether a complicated search order is actually clear to your users and whether you'd be better off with 3 different searches - but that's another question).

So, to do that you need a slightly more complicated query with a-lot-more-complicated ordering. I'm using `CASE` to set an order based on your criteria:

```
q = Article.where("user_id = ? or article_type = 'public'", current_user.id)

# As in the query above, join in the vote row for the current user on the article
q = q.joins("left join votes on article_id = articles.id and user_id = #{User.sanitize(current_user.id)}"
q = q.where(votes: { id: nil })

# First order by whether the user is the current user or not
q = q.order("case when articles.user_id = #{User.sanitize(current_user.id)} then 1 else 2 end")

# Next order by whether the user has voted or not
q = q.order("case when votes.id is not null then 1 else 2 end")

articles = q # or q.limit(100) or q.page(1) or somesuch
```

The case statement in the order clause translates the condition into either a 1 or a 2. So, for example in the first order clause. If the article's user id matches the current user then `1` will be used for sorting and otherwise `2` will be used. Therefore the user's articles will appear higher in the list of articles. The next criteria to sort on is whether the user has voted on the article or not. So it ends up as something like `order by 1, 1`.

That should do what you want (although I haven't tested it so you might it might need a tweak here or there).

Comment: Thanks a lot Shadwell for the answer. I am a bit confused, what does "case then 1 else 2 end" do? and q.where(votes: { id: nil })?
I am also sending a parameter :word to search articles by owner username and article title.

Comment: I've added a bit explaining the case in the `order(...)`. The `votes: { id: nil }` just translates to SQL like `votes.id is null`.